# Overloading operator without having a class

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Can we use operator overloading on non-objects? e.g adding two `vector<int>`. Or do I need to make a class having `vector<int>` and then overload the `+` operator.

Also, I want to know if it is possible to have 2 different types of operands in a binary operator. If yes, how?

Comment: `std::vector<something>` is not a class?

Comment: You can do it:
std::vector<X> operator +(std::vector<X> const& v1, std::vector<X> const& v2) {//some code here;}
int operator +(std::vector<X> const& v1, std::string const& s2) {//some code here;}

Comment: @down-voters, please comment!

Comment: _"Also"_ One question per question please. Ideally, a coherent one.

Comment: The downvotes are for that plus the fact that you put near-ZERO effort into this question. You didn't check the formatting of your type names, and you couldn't even be bothered to capitalise the word "I".

Answer (score 2):

> Can we use operator overloading on non-objects?

Operators are essentially implemented as functions and can accept a similar range of types as functions do.

There are a [few restrictions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators#Overloaded_operators), in particular, it is *limited by the fact that at least one argument must be a `class` or `enum`* (user or library type).

In addition, *there are some operators that have to be implemented as member functions*, so they will be associated with a class, but many can be declared and defined outside of a class.

The exact number of arguments is determined by the operator being implemented. Unary operators accept 1 argument, binary operators accept 2 arguments.

Generally, the advice is to offer behaviour similar to the [canonical forms](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators#Canonical_implementations), but the language itself does not limit your implementation to just that behaviour.

> Also, I want to know if it is possible to have 2 different types of operands in a binary operator. If yes, how?

Yes. Again, just as functions do.

Comment: No.  Operator overloading must involve at least one operand of class or enum type.  (That is, a user or library defined type, not a build-in type).  So  `void * operator(const char*lhs, const int* rhs) { return NULL;}` won't cmpile.

Comment: @MartinBonner. Correct I'll add that for clarification.

Comment: operator overloading with two struct type is allowed if I am not mistaken. I tried this using the example 'struct A
{
    int a;
    char b;
};

struct A operator+(struct A& var1, struct A& var2)
{
    struct A result;
    result.a=var1.a+var2.a;
    return(result);
}'

Comment: @Rajesh. Correct, a user overloaded operator requires at least one user type to distinguish itself from the built in operators.

Comment: Request you to update your answer indicating this (atleast one user defined type)

Comment: @Rajesh I'm not sure I follow, it is already there _There are a few restrictions, in particular, it is limited by the fact that at least one argument must be a class or enum._

Comment: I did not considered structure as a class. That is why I thought this statement might make it better "There are a few restrictions, in particular, it is limited by the fact that at least one argument must be a user defined type such as structure, class or enum"

Comment: @Rajesh. No problem. From the cppreference, http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/classes, _The class keys `struct` and `class` are indistinguishable in C++, except that the default access mode and default inheritance_

Answer (score 2):

> Can we use operator overloading on non-objects? e.g adding two vector.

I think you meant to ask whether it's possible to use operator overloading **outside of a class definition**. And yes, it definitely is possible as already stated by other people here. Here's a simple example of overloading the '+' operator for a custom 'MyClass' type:

```
MyClass operator+(const MyClass& a, const MyClass& b)
{
    return MyClass(a.value + b.value);
}
```

However, there is a reason why `std::vector` doesn't have overloads for arithmetic operators as the result is ambiguous. Do you want  '+' to link two vectors together or should the components be added? How do you handle vectors which differ in size? Often, containers of the STL provide special methods for these purposes and don't rely on operators when it's not clear so make sure you've checked the [specification of std::vectors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

You're free to implement such operators as you see fit, especially with your own types but you risk creating unintuitive behaviour and ultimately, bad code. In the case of `std::vector`, it might be better to write a function with a descriptive name which operates on `std::vector` in the way you desire:

```
std::vector<int> addComponents(const std::vector<int>& a, const std::vector<int>& b);
```

Answer (score -2):

> Can we use operator overloading on non-objects? e.g adding two vector[?]

The premise of your question is broken, because **a `vector<int>` is an object**.

Overload all you like.

> Also, i want to know if it is possible to have 2 different types of operands in a binary operator.

Try it.

> If yes, how?

By typing it.

Comment: @fantaghirocco: Lol? What about this is a new question? Stop abusing the review system.

Comment: oops, I let myself be tricked by the multiple question marks: my apologies sir :)